# Kubernetes do I need to include port when directing?

Tags: nginx, flask, kubernetes

I have an application running in K8s. It has 3 microservices and nginx in front of them.
Each redirection goes through nginx first and is proxied as specified.
My flask app is having issues redirecting without the port number. I run k8s locally via minikube. Whenever I redirect to another page the url doesn't include port number, which throws me an error.

```
if usernamedata == None:
    print("Could not log in")   
else:
    if passworddata == password:
        print("Logged in")
        return redirect("/user/{0}".format(username))
```

Nginx is the only service exposed and its url is
`http://192.168.99.107:31699`
With my redirection in flask I get redirected to `http://192.168.99.107/user/David`, which throws me connection refused.
If I add port number and make it `http://192.168.99.107:31699/user/David` it works fine.
Do I need to specify port number when redirecting? What if the service is down and recreated?
Also, this is my service definition for nginx:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    svc: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app:  nginx-app
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
   - port:  80
```

How can I make redirection within flask app work?

Comment: Have you setup load balancer correctly in minikube? What does `$ minikube service nginx --url` return?

Comment: it returns `http://192.168.99.107:31699`

Comment: Your high port number is set dynamically (random) by Kubernetes, because you did not specify it explicitly. See answer below on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

If service is down and recreated and you want to retain same high port number for your service you need to specify `nodePort` and change type of service to `NodePort`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  labels:
    svc: nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort # type is set to NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80 # Service's internal cluster IP
    targetPort: 80 # target port of the backing pods
    nodePort: 31699 # service will be only available via this port for each cluster node if recreated
  selector:
    app:  nginx-app
```

Within your Python code (If Service starts before Pod):

```
import os 

...
service_host = os.environ.get("NGINX_SERVICE_HOST")
service_port = os.environ.get("NGINX_SERVICE_PORT")
...
redirect(f"http://{service_host}:{service_port}/user/{username}")
```

Comment: So in flask do I need to explicitly specify the port as well?

Comment: Yes, your options : hard code, pass via environment variables, downward API or query internal DNS.

Comment: so where do I add the port in `return redirect("/user/{0}".format(username))`? Adding it at the beginning causes me to be redirected to `http://192.168.99.107/31699/user/david`

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understood your question. Is not it possible to do `redirect("http://192.168.99.107:31699/user/{0}".format(username))` ? You can also try to redirect by DNS name instead of IP address , i.e.  `http://nginx` ?

Comment: `redirect("http://192.168.99.107:31699/user/{0}".format(username))` works but is not an ideal solution for me. Thank you for your help, I will leave this as it is for now and try something more when I understand k8s better.

Comment: Other options would be to put Ingress in front of your load balancer, use DNS instead of IP. You can also get Service IP and portfrom your Pod's environment variables (if you start Pod after you start the Service). See updated answer.